# Uber API Webhooks for requests.status_changed not firing, webhooks for requests.receipt_ready are

Tags: webhooks, uber-api

I have a test app written in Ruby on Rails and visible to an ngrok IP. I created a sandbox controller that lets me change the status of the sandbox trip with a click of a button.

Until today (during a demo of course; it had worked 25 minutes earlier), it was posting webhook events to my ngrok IP for every status change, of type requests.status_changed. Currently, if I change a processing ride to "accepting", "arriving", or "in_progress", I get the appropriate responses back from the sandbox but no webhooks are created. If I change the ride to "driver_canceled" or "completed", I get a requests.receipt_ready webhook event.

I'm happy to show code if that will help (**EDIT: I am showing code below**), but since a) I get correct answers back from the sandbox on status change (though no webhook post), and b) I get webhook posts for receipt notification, I assume that:

- I am talking to the sandbox correctly
- I am not having a network or firewall issue preventing the webhook from reaching my server

I'm dependent on the status_changed webhooks to give me the notification I need to take additional action. Is anything going on with those or is there a set of things I should be looking at to determine why those are failing?

---

Update:

I'm doing this in Rails. I use a class called UberConnection to connect, which basically is HTTParty:

```
class UberConnection
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2'
  headers "Accept-Language" => "en_US", "Content-Type" => 
  "application/json"
  debug_output $stdout
end
```

I use ngrok to get a publicly visible name for the webhook. I have my webhook configured to listen for events where event_type = "requests.status_changed". They create UberEvent ActiveRecord objects and check for duplicates or filter events not matching the ACTIVE_EVENTS list:

```
ACTIVE_EVENTS = ["requests.status_changed"]

if (!UberEvent.where(event_id: params["event_id"]).blank? || !ACTIVE_EVENTS.include?(params["event_type"]))
  Rails.logger.debug("Ignoring duplicate or filtered notice")
  return head :ok
end
```

I also have a sandbox controller that will change the status of a ride in progress so I can simulate the ride life cycle:

```
def ops_accepted
  UberConnection.put("/sandbox/requests/#{params[:ride_id]}",
    headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{Uber.token}"},
    body: {status: "accepted"}.to_json)
    flash[:notice] = "Changed ride to Accepted"
    redirect_to action: :operator
end
```

and similar for the other life cycle types.

**Expected Behavior**
Once I schedule a ride and it's in processing state, I should be able to hit the button that fires ops_accepted and have the ride changed to accepted. This should cause a webhook event to fire indicating the status changed, and I can take additional actions based on that.

**Actual Behavior**
Everything but the webhook event fires.

**Submit A New Ride**

```
Started GET "/sandbox" for 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11 at 2017-07-26 08:35:46 -0400
Cannot render console from 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WebhooksController#operator as HTML
  Uber Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "ubers".* FROM "ubers" ORDER BY "ubers"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
opening connection to sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
opened
starting SSL for sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
SSL established
<- "GET /v1.2/requests/current HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en_US\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Bearer [TOKEN REDACTED]\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: sandbox-api.uber.com\r\n\r\n"
-> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
-> "Server: nginx\r\n"
-> "Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 12:35:45 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 431\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Content-Geo-System: wgs-84\r\n"
-> "Content-Language: en\r\n"
-> "Etag: W/\"e9fda87d668bbe0f46ec27d8557b110b03c8c422\"\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: uberex-sandbox\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: optimus\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800\r\n"
-> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n"
-> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\n"
-> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 431 bytes...
-> "{\"status\":\"processing\",\"product_id\":\"6d898741-0175-4c71-ad5f-93fc66270d6a\",\"destination\":{\"latitude\":33.754177,\"longitude\":-84.371736},\"driver\":null,\"pickup\":{\"latitude\":33.7539854,\"region\":{\"latitude\":33.7489,\"country_name\":\"United States\",\"country_code\":\"US\",\"name\":\"Atlanta\",\"longitude\":-84.3881},\"eta\":6,\"longitude\":-84.3755874},\"request_id\":\"f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9\",\"location\":null,\"vehicle\":null,\"shared\":false}"
read 431 bytes
Conn close
  Rendering webhooks/operator.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered webhooks/operator.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 795ms (Views: 27.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

**Change to Accepted**

```
Started PUT "/webhooks/accept/f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9" for 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11 at 2017-07-26 08:48:22 -0400
Cannot render console from 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WebhooksController#ops_accepted as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"PIHCTPkaOpa8RrsvT4D+TF0PR1UvY8uukh9SC2MRw1o5StFZYo0PNtn1g0W6QQh/2f7/hQSDSVVy8CMLJv/GYg==", "ride_id"=>"f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9"}
  Uber Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ubers".* FROM "ubers" ORDER BY "ubers"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
opening connection to sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
opened
starting SSL for sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
SSL established
<- "PUT /v1.2/sandbox/requests/f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en_US\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Bearer [TOKEN REDACTED]\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: sandbox-api.uber.com\r\nContent-Length: 21\r\n\r\n"
<- "{\"status\":\"accepted\"}"
-> "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\n"
-> "Server: nginx\r\n"
-> "Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 12:48:23 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Content-Language: en\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: uberex-sandbox\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: optimus\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800\r\n"
-> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n"
-> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\n"
-> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
Conn close
Redirected to http://edgexpress.ngrok.io/sandbox
Completed 302 Found in 1010ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/sandbox" for 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11 at 2017-07-26 08:48:23 -0400
Cannot render console from 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WebhooksController#operator as HTML
  Uber Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "ubers".* FROM "ubers" ORDER BY "ubers"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
opening connection to sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
opened
starting SSL for sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
SSL established
<- "GET /v1.2/requests/current HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en_US\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Bearer [TOKEN REDACTED]\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: sandbox-api.uber.com\r\n\r\n"
-> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
-> "Server: nginx\r\n"
-> "Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 12:48:24 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 804\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Content-Geo-System: wgs-84\r\n"
-> "Content-Language: en\r\n"
-> "Etag: W/\"c1f9c6d51c7094d1e7789222a522aa1d3f304068\"\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: uberex-sandbox\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: optimus\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800\r\n"
-> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n"
-> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\n"
-> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 804 bytes...
-> "{\"status\":\"accepted\",\"product_id\":\"6d898741-0175-4c71-ad5f-93fc66270d6a\",\"destination\":{\"latitude\":33.754177,\"eta\":2,\"longitude\":-84.371736},\"driver\":{\"phone_number\":\"(555)555-5555\",\"rating\":4.9,\"picture_url\":\"https:\\/\\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\\/uberex-sandbox\\/images\\/driver.jpg\",\"name\":\"John\",\"sms_number\":null},\"pickup\":{\"latitude\":33.7539854,\"region\":{\"latitude\":33.7489,\"country_name\":\"United States\",\"country_code\":\"US\",\"name\":\"Atlanta\",\"longitude\":-84.3881},\"eta\":1,\"longitude\":-84.3755874},\"request_id\":\"f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9\",\"location\":{\"latitude\":33.7559,\"bearing\":-178,\"longitude\":-84.37212},\"vehicle\":{\"make\":\"Toyota\",\"picture_url\":\"https:\\/\\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\\/uberex-sandbox\\/images\\/prius.jpg\",\"model\":\"Prius\",\"license_plate\":\"UBER-PLATE\"},\"shared\":false}"
read 804 bytes
Conn close
  Rendering webhooks/operator.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered webhooks/operator.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 965ms (Views: 28.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

As you can see, no webhook fired. Now, let's close the ride out with a driver cancel.

**Driver Cancel**

```
Started PUT "/webhooks/cancel/f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9" for 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11 at 2017-07-26 08:51:08 -0400
Cannot render console from 2600:1005:b06a:1a83:9818:4356:ceda:ca11! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WebhooksController#ops_cancelled as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[REDACTED]", "ride_id"=>"f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9"}
  Uber Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "ubers".* FROM "ubers" ORDER BY "ubers"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
opening connection to sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
opened
starting SSL for sandbox-api.uber.com:443...
SSL established
<- "PUT /v1.2/sandbox/requests/f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Language: en_US\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Bearer [REDACTED]\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: sandbox-api.uber.com\r\nContent-Length: 28\r\n\r\n"
<- "{\"status\":\"driver_canceled\"}"
-> "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\n"
-> "Server: nginx\r\n"
-> "Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 12:51:08 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Content-Language: en\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: uberex-sandbox\r\n"
-> "X-Uber-App: optimus\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800\r\n"
-> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n"
-> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\n"
-> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
Conn close
Redirected to http://edgexpress.ngrok.io/sandbox
Completed 302 Found in 582ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

Started POST "/webhooks/event" for 104.36.193.85 at 2017-07-26 08:51:10 -0400
Cannot render console from 104.36.193.85! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WebhooksController#event as */*
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"6b8e9684-c1c9-448b-92ef-54f9bbde53d0", "resource_href"=>"https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9/receipt", "meta"=>{"status"=>"ready", "rider_id"=>"8Gb4HQ4kVZIq-Z6nR_kKYGBO_tjV1JqyU2VRJJdICrKLJDFVSv34MqsGfKZI0JO6d7-ELIws7Ia_YhwCmbvVHXRzwdIzEDOXs4aTrPRljXML10yOpwEKTn1sCyPlHmLT4g==", "user_id"=>"55d5e34c-1a9f-4dd8-87fe-1764678eea94", "resource_id"=>"f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9"}, "event_type"=>"requests.receipt_ready", "event_time"=>1501073468, "webhook"=>{"event_id"=>"6b8e9684-c1c9-448b-92ef-54f9bbde53d0", "resource_href"=>"https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9/receipt", "meta"=>{"status"=>"ready", "rider_id"=>"8Gb4HQ4kVZIq-Z6nR_kKYGBO_tjV1JqyU2VRJJdICrKLJDFVSv34MqsGfKZI0JO6d7-ELIws7Ia_YhwCmbvVHXRzwdIzEDOXs4aTrPRljXML10yOpwEKTn1sCyPlHmLT4g==", "user_id"=>"55d5e34c-1a9f-4dd8-87fe-1764678eea94", "resource_id"=>"f14877e5-f060-4c4a-be91-bb66866238b9"}, "event_type"=>"requests.receipt_ready", "event_time"=>1501073468}}
Comparing 6b8e9684-c1c9-448b-92ef-54f9bbde53d0 to what's in db. . .
  UberEvent Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "uber_events".* FROM "uber_events" WHERE "uber_events"."event_id" = ?  [["event_id", "6b8e9684-c1c9-448b-92ef-54f9bbde53d0"]]
Ignoring duplicate or filtered notice
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
```

As you can see, the webhook posted with the receipt information, which means that it's not a block between me and the webhooks poster, or a misconfiguration. The webhook simply isn't firing for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

We are not currently seeing webhook issues when status of the trip is changed in the sandbox. I have tested with my test application and I received webhooks for all status changes where webhook suppose to be fired. Please check screen print bellow:
[image]

Comment: Hi Sasa, I'm still seeing problems. I will update the ticket with more detail.

Comment: Do you still have a problem with webhooks?

Comment: Yes, this is broken still. I put the app onto a server in Google Cloud and got the same results, so that means it wasn't my machine or my use of ngrok that caused the problem. I get some of the webhooks (receipt ones) but not the ride ones, so that means that it's not my webhook listener. Did you change anything in the sandbox or are you seeing issues there? 

I also provided substantial additional context above to explain and rule out errors on my side.

Comment: There was a problem and it is fixed now. Thanks reporting it.